# Increase Steps in 2D Self Avoiding Random Walk

Tags: fortran

I am trying to increase the number of possible steps in the following Fortran self avoiding random walk program.

Increasing the number of steps would result in more accuracy regarding the square  mean distance

I would appropriate your solutions and suggestions.

```
PROGRAM Two_dimensional_Self_Avoiding__Random_Walks

  implicit none

  integer, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: lattice 
  integer, dimension(1:46):: na
  integer :: i,x,y,xt,yt,id,step,xx, ns,n,ii,III,choice
  real :: r,dis,dis2,square,d,d2
  Logical :: terminate,newsite


  CALL RANDOM_SEED()
             ! intial values for end to end distance 


  read(*,*) choice 
if (choice == 1) then 

  print*, ' Enter ns and n '
  read(*,*) ns 

na = (/(III, III=5, 50, 1)/) 

  do ii= 1, 46

 dis = 0.0; dis2 = 0.0 

 n = na(ii)

  allocate(lattice(-n:n,-n:n)) 

  CALL walks()                          ! self avoiding walks
IF (ALLOCATED (lattice)) DEALLOCATE (lattice)

enddo 

elseif (choice == 2) then 


 print*, ' Enter ns and n '
  read(*,*) ns , n

dis = 0.0; dis2 = 0.0 
 allocate(lattice(-n:n,-n:n)) 
CALL walks()    

endif




CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE walks

    DO i = 1,ns

    lattice = 0; x = 0; y = 0
    step = 0; terminate = .FALSE.


    DO WHILE ((.NOT. terminate) .AND. (step <= n))
    xt = x; yt = y
    xx = lattice(x+1,y)+lattice(x-1,y) &
    +lattice(x,y+1)+lattice(x,y-1)

    IF (xx == 4) THEN
    terminate = .TRUE.
    ELSE
    newsite = .FALSE.

    DO WHILE (.NOT. newsite)
    CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(r)
    id = INT(r*4.0)

    IF (id == 0) THEN
    x = xt + 1; y = yt
    ELSEIF (id == 1) THEN
    x = xt - 1; y = yt
    ELSEIF (id == 2) THEN
    x = xt; y = yt + 1
    ELSEIF (id == 3) THEN
    x = xt; y = yt - 1 
    ENDIF

    IF (lattice(x,y) == 0) newsite = .TRUE.

    ENDDO

    step = step + 1; lattice(x,y) = 1
    ENDIF



    write(7,*) x,y

    ENDDO



    write(10,*),step

    square = float(x**2+y**2)
    dis = dis + sqrt(square); dis2 = dis2 + square
    d = dis/ns; d2=dis2/ns




    ENDDO
    write(11,*), ns,n, d, d2
     print*, ns,n, d, d2
    END SUBROUTINE walks


END PROGRAM Two_dimensional_Self_Avoiding__Random_Walks
```

Comment: I don't find this very clear: what is it you are asking?

Comment: Is the program not working correctly? What exactly you need to achieve?